# Use Laravel Passport with Angular 6

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel application in which I'm using Passport for authentication. I have multiple questions about the Passport authentication:

- Why does Passport store all tokens ( in table `oauth_access_tokens` ) even if the user has a new token and can I avoid this huge storage?
- How to consume this token in Angular part? Can I just save it in LocalStorage or Cookies and redirect the user? But how to verify if it's a valid token?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens can be removed by using one of the artisan commands that come with it:

```
php artisan passport:purge --expired
```

So you could call this artisan command using the scheduler, say once a day.

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#purging-tokens for additional info.

As for your second question, well there are various ways to do that. One way is explained here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript , which explains how you can add a middleware which attaches a `laravel_token` cookie to each request. This cookie is then automatically sent from your JavaScript requests, and will authenticate the user.

Comment: thanks it's clear for me now, juste for the first question, i wish i can find a way to delete token after user make new authentication or logout, so on in production, i don't need to purge every time. Thanks again

Comment: You can probably delete those manually using `DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('user_id', $userId)->delete()` , just before a new one is requested. There's probably a way to hook into that. The artisan command is an easier solution though.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a good idea too, once the application is in production i will see which is better, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Help please,   Command "passport:purge" is not defined.